# How to represent any event and any function in C#?

Tags: c#, events

I had the idea of developing a class to manage events unsubscriptions in a safe way so I don't have to manually write `-=` to each event subscription of this system when the time comes (in this system there are groups of events that are subscribed and unsubscribed together).

I thought of creating a class that manages a `Dictionary` where the *key* is an event (any possible event) and the *value* is a method (any possible method). This way I would have a method to subscribe a function to an event and it will do that alongside registering the pair in the `Dictionary`; and another method to unsubscribe all events added with this class (which would just iterate the dictionary and unsubscribe all events).

Thing is: I can't find how to have a common type of any event that I could use as generic argument to the dictonary's key and also I don't know how to represent any function in C# to set as the dictionary's value. In C/C++ I could just treat them both as void pointers as all I would need is the pointer of the function itself.

Is that even possible to do using C#? Are there existing better methods/strategies to accomplish that?

Comment: If you have groups of events, have you considered replacing them with one event and an event argument to describe any additional information?

Comment: @JonasH I can't do that because 1 event can be in more than 1 of those groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to come up with a way of generating the key for the event, since you can't use a plain `event` as a dictionary key. One way to do that would be to concatenate the event's declaring class name with the name of the event.

Then you could use a dictionary using that as a key, with a `List<Action>` as the value. Here, the `Action` would be a delegate that you could call to unsubscribe.

You could wrap that dictionary in a class to provide `Subscribe()` and `Unsubscribe()` methods like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string eventKey = test.GetType().FullName + '.' + nameof(test.MyEvent);
            subs.Subscribe(eventKey, () => test.MyEvent += handler, () => test.MyEvent -= handler);
            subs.Subscribe(eventKey, () => test.MyEvent += handler, () => test.MyEvent -= handler);
            test.RaiseEvent(); // Two handlers called.
            subs.Unsubscribe(eventKey);
            test.RaiseEvent(); // No handlers called (both were unsubscribed).
        }

        static void handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling event.");
        }

        static readonly Test test = new Test();

        static readonly EventSubscriptions subs = new EventSubscriptions();

    }

    public class EventSubscriptions
    {
        public void Subscribe(string key, Action subscribe, Action unsubscribe)
        {
            subscriptions.TryGetValue(key, out var subs);

            if (subs == null)
            {
                subs = new List<Action>();
                subscriptions.Add(key, subs);
            }

            subscribe();
            subs.Add(unsubscribe);
        }

        public void Unsubscribe(string key)
        {
            subscriptions.TryGetValue(key, out var subs);

            if (subs != null)
            {
                foreach (var unsub in subs)
                {
                    unsub();
                }

                subscriptions.Remove(key);
            }
        }

        readonly Dictionary<string, List<Action>> subscriptions = new Dictionary<string, List<Action>>();
    }

    class Test
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;

        public void RaiseEvent()
        {
            MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your event handlers are of the `void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)` variety, your dictionary would be `Dictionary<string, Action<object,EventArgs>>` (assuming you wanted the key to be string - anything else would work too)

Comment: The events can have other prototypes than `void MyHandler(object, EventArgs)`. I didn't understand how I would use the dictionary key as string too. Are you suggesting to pass the `nameof()` of the event to access it using reflection?